# How to Pass 'WSS-Password Type' , 'WSS TimeToLive' in Restassured

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured

We are using RestAssured for SOAP calls. The API that we are testing requires 'WSS-Password Type' and 'WSS TimeToLive' to be set. We are able to do it easily in [SoapUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoapUI) as we need to add properties in properties pane on left bottom side. However, for doing it programmatically, we don't know how to pass it. We are using the below statement:

```
this.request.given().header("WSS-Password Type", "PasswordText","WSS TimeToLive", "5000","Authentication Type","No Authorization","Content-Type", "text/xml").body(payload).when().request(Method.POST, uri_path);
```

It is giving the below error in response:

> An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header

This is a showstopper for us. How can we fix it?